# Can't figure out how to make this form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am trying to make a scheduling system using PHP and MySQL.  I have it so i can view/edit/delete employees, equipment and customers.  The final thing I need to do is make the schedule.  I have the following tables

```
-- Lookup table for employee positions.
CREATE TABLE `EmployeePosition` (
    `EmployeePositionID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `PK_Position` PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeePositionID`),
CONSTRAINT `UK_Position_Name` UNIQUE (`Name`)
);

-- Lookup table for eqipment types.
CREATE TABLE `EquipmentType` (
`EquipmentTypeID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `PK_EquipmentType` PRIMARY KEY (`EquipmentTypeID`),
CONSTRAINT `UK_EquipmentType_Name` UNIQUE (`Name`)
);

-- Employee information.
CREATE TABLE `Employee` (
`EmployeeID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`Email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`FirstName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`LastName` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`EmployeePositionID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`HomePhone` VARCHAR(32),
`CellPhone` VARCHAR(32),
`AccessLevel` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`IsDisabled` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
`PwdHash` CHAR(40) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'X',
CONSTRAINT `PK_Employee` PRIMARY KEY (`EmployeeID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_Employee_EmployeePositionID` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeePositionID`)     REFERENCES `EmployeePosition` (`EmployeePositionID`),
CONSTRAINT `UK_Employee_Email` UNIQUE (`Email`)
);

-- Customer information.
CREATE TABLE `Customer` (
`CustomerID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`Name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
`Address1` VARCHAR(100),
`Address2` VARCHAR(100),
`City` VARCHAR(100),
`State` VARCHAR(2),
`ZipCode` VARCHAR(20),
`Phone` VARCHAR(32),
`Fax` VARCHAR(32),
`IsDisabled` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT `PK_Customer` PRIMARY KEY (`CustomerID`),
CONSTRAINT `UK_Customer_Name` UNIQUE (`Name`)
);

-- Equipment information.
CREATE TABLE `Equipment` (
`EquipmentID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`Number` VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL,
`EquipmentTypeID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`IsDisabled` TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
CONSTRAINT `PK_Equipment` PRIMARY KEY (`EquipmentID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_Equipment_EquipmentTypeID` FOREIGN KEY (`EquipmentTypeID`) REFERENCES   `EquipmentType` (`EquipmentTypeID`),
CONSTRAINT `UK_Equipment_Number` UNIQUE (`Number`)
);

-- Basic job information.
CREATE TABLE `ScheduledJob` (
`ScheduledJobId` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`CustomerID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`JobDate` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`ReportTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`StartTime` DATETIME NOT NULL,
`JobDescription` MEDIUMTEXT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT `PK_ScheduledJob` PRIMARY KEY (`ScheduledJobId`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ScheduledJob_CustomerID` FOREIGN KEY (`CustomerID`) REFERENCES  `Customer` (`CustomerID`)
);

-- Employees tied to jobs.
CREATE TABLE `ScheduledEmployee` (
`ScheduledEmployeeID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`ScheduledJobID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`EmployeeID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`Notes` MEDIUMTEXT,
CONSTRAINT `PK_ScheduledEmployee` PRIMARY KEY (`ScheduledEmployeeID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ScheduledEmployee_ScheduledJobID` FOREIGN KEY (`ScheduledJobID`) REFERENCES `ScheduledJob` (`ScheduledJobID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ScheduledEmployee_EmployeeID` FOREIGN KEY (`EmployeeID`) REFERENCES `Employee` (`EmployeeID`),
CONSTRAINT `UK_ScheduledEmployee` UNIQUE (`ScheduledJobID`, `EmployeeID`)
);

-- Equipment tied to jobs.
CREATE TABLE `ScheduledEquipment` (
`ScheduledEquipmentID` INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
`ScheduledJobID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`EquipmentID` INTEGER NOT NULL,
`Notes` MEDIUMTEXT,
CONSTRAINT `PK_ScheduledEquipment` PRIMARY KEY (`ScheduledEquipmentID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ScheduledEquipment_ScheduledJobID` FOREIGN KEY (`ScheduledJobID`) REFERENCES `ScheduledJob` (`ScheduledJobID`),
CONSTRAINT `FK_ScheduledEquipment_EquipmentID` FOREIGN KEY (`EquipmentID`) REFERENCES `Equipment` (`EquipmentID`),
CONSTRAINT `UK_ScheduledEquipment` UNIQUE (`ScheduledJobID`, `EquipmentID`)
);
```

The form i am trying to make should look something like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ScheduledJobID  JobDate  ReportTime  StartTime  CustomerID EmployeeID  EquipmentID  JobDescription
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

CustomerID, EmployeeID, EquipmentID should all be dropown boxes that I can choose from information already in the
database.  I am not sure where to start...Can someone help me please.  I do know how to make the dropdowns as i already use them
in my add forms.

Basically i want to show the job date, time to report to the office, time to report to the customer (StartTime), The customer we are working for,
The employees on the job, the equipment on the job, and a job description....We are a service company and this is how we schedule.  We currently
do it on paper and I am trying to get us into the 21st century.

Comment: SELECT * from the jobs table and LEFT JOIN all the equipment and employee tables onto that. Then just display it. I'm not quite sure what you mean by your dropdown menus... can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Sorry..what i mean is a list...with a down arrow and it shows the data from a certain row in the database that you can select

Comment: what would be the query to LEFT JOIN two tables to one...i know how to do it with one other table...but not two

Comment: I understand what a dropdown *is* but I don't understand what you want it to contain... I assume you mean to show 1 row (of the table) per job. And inside that row you want each field to be a dropdown menu. Now a dropdown menu consists of multiple values, while the job only has 1 value per field... so where do the other values come from ?

Comment: You can use 2 LEFT JOIN one after the other inside the same query. Just repeat the LEFT JOIN syntax

Comment: hmm....in the schedule..i would want to use dropdowns to select and employee, customer, and equipment..all different dropdown boxes.  The selected item from each box needs to be saved to make one completed job on the schedule

Comment: So something like this: SELECT \`ScheduledJob\`.\`ScheduledJobID\`, \`ScheduledJob\`.\`JobDate\`, \`ScheduledJob\`.\`ReportTime\`, \`ScheduledJob\`.\`StartTime\`, \`ScheduledJob\`.\`CustomerID\`, \`ScheduledEmployee\`.\`EmployeeID\`,\`ScheduledEquipment\`.\`EquipmentID\`\`ScheduledJob\`.\`JobDescription\` FROM \`ScheduledJob\` LEFT JOIN \`ScheduledEmployee\` ON (\`ScheduledEmployee\`.\`ScheduledJobID\`=\`ScheduledJob\`.\`ScheduledJobId\`) LEFT JOIN \`ScheduledEquipment\` ON (\`ScheduledEquipment\`.\`ScheduledJobID\`=\`ScheduledJob\`.\`ScheduledJobId\`)

Comment: Ahh... I see... well, what I would suggest then is to select all data for each of those fields from the appropriate tables. Store these locally in an array. Then for each job in the jobs resultset, you loop over those fields; and if they match the person/equipment/whatever, add a selected="selected" in there, otherwise just display it. And repeat that for each row again.

Comment: awsome..thanks for that...any chance you can show me a generic was of displaying it and I can fix it up from there...just somewhere to start..i would really appreciate it.

Comment: I am getting this error when i try to run that query.......#1054 - Unknown column 'ScheduledEquipment.EquipmentID`Schâ€Œâ€‹eduledJob.JobDescription' in 'field list'

Comment: yeah, I made a small typo in there, after \`ScheduledEquipment.EquipmentID\` there should be another comma :)

Comment: ok..cleared up on error...now just have this one....#1054 - Unknown column 'Schâ€Œâ€‹eduledJob.JobDescription' in 'field list'

Comment: According to your table output above, your ScheduledJob table should contain a JobDescription column. So that is strange. However, for some odd reason your post contain various incorrectly encoded characters... perhaps you have a problem with copying the query?

Comment: You are right...something went afoul during my copying...i copied it again and it worked like a charm...thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like:

```
<?php
// assuming mysqli
$db = new mysqli(...);

// initialize variables
$employees = array();
$equipment = array();

$r = $db->query("SELECT `EmployeeID`, `FirstName` FROM `Employee`");
while($employee = $r->fetch_object()){ 
    $employees[$employee->EmployeeID] = $employee->FirstName;
}
// same for equipment

echo '<table>';
echo '<tr>';
echo '<th>ScheduledJobID</th><th>JobDate</th><th>ReportTime</th><th>StartTime</th><th>CustomerID</th><th>EmployeeID</th><th>EquipmentID</th><th>JobDescription</th>';
echo '</tr>';

// get your jobs
$result = $db->query("SELECT `ScheduledJob`.`ScheduledJobID`, `ScheduledJob`.`JobDate`, `ScheduledJob`.`ReportTime`, `ScheduledJob`.`StartTime`, `ScheduledJob`.`CustomerID`, `ScheduledEmployee`.`EmployeeID`,`ScheduledEquipment`.`EquipmentID`, `ScheduledJob`.`JobDescription` FROM `ScheduledJob` LEFT JOIN `ScheduledEmployee` ON (`ScheduledEmployee`.`ScheduledJobID`=`ScheduledJob`.`ScheduledJobId`) LEFT JOIN `ScheduledEquipment` ON (`ScheduledEquipment`.`ScheduledJobID`=`ScheduledJob`.`ScheduledJobId`)");
while($job = $result->fetch_object()){ 
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>',$job->ScheduledJobID,'</td>';
    echo '<td>',$job->JobDate,'</td>';
    echo '<td>',$job->ReportTime,'</td>';
    echo '<td>',$job->StartTime,'</td>';
    echo '<td><select name="employee_in_job[',$job->ScheduledJobID,']">';
    foreach($employees as $id=>$name) { 
        if($id == $job->EmployeeID) {
            // selected emplyee according to your joblist
            echo '<option value="',$id,'" selected="selected">', $name, '</option>';
        } else {
            echo '<option value="',$id,'">', $name, '</option>';
        }
    }
    echo '</select></td>';
    echo '<td>',$job->EquipmentID,'</td>'; // same thing for equipment, but you can do that yourself
    echo '<td>',$job->JobDescription,'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Comment: I keep getting this error......Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in /home/tinker74/public_html/learning/schedule/admin/schedule1.php on line 13

Comment: Made a typo, that variable should be $r obviously, not $result (fixed in the answer). But I'm starting to wonder how proficient you are with PHP with this comment... do you actually understand what this code does exactly? :s

Comment: you are correct...i dont know very much PHP..i am still learning